# How do i set the current logged in user as default in Django view when no url parameters are given

Tags: python, django, web-applications

i want the /profile/ route to be accessible without having to pass any url argument

This is my profile View:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    ctx = {"username" : username}
    return render(request, "raynet/profile.html",ctx)
```

This is my url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.landing),
    path('home/', views.home),
    path('profile/', views.profile),
    path('profile/<username>', views.profile),
    path('apps/', views.apps),
    path('signin/', views.signin),
    path('signup/', views.signup),
    path('testing/', views.testing),
    path('signout/', views.signout),
]
```

It works fine if i specify a username in the url, but it doesnt work if i just go to /profile/
I want to get the current logged in user as default when no url variable is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username=None):   
    ctx = {"username" : username if username else request.user.username}
    return render(request, "raynet/profile.html",ctx)
```

Here I am writing username parameter as keyword argument, so that username default value is None. Then using if else logic, I am assigning username value from argument or from `request.user.username`.